# ArrayList Size 0

Tags: java

I am new to StackOverflow and I am really sorry for bad formatting as I could not arrange it exactly I guess.

My problem is when I run the TestHeaps class the ArrayLists that are the basis of my Heaps does not work in that when I try to add an element, the size is stuck at 0 (zero).

Can anyone suggest a help on why this might be the case?

```
package HeapLab;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

    /**
     * This class implements a generic max heap.
     * 
     * @author Sesh Venugopal
     *
     * @param <T> Type of data stored in the heap, must implement method compareTo of
     *              generic Comparable<T> interface, to compare priorities.
     */
    public class MaxHeap<T extends Comparable<T>> 
    {
        /**
         * Stores the heap items.
         */
       @SuppressWarnings("FieldMayBeFinal")
        private ArrayList<T> items;

        /**
         * Maintains iteration point. 
         */
        int cursor;

        /**
         * Initializes a new instance by setting up storage of given capacity.
         * 
         * @param cap Initial storage capacity.
         */
        public MaxHeap(int cap) 
       {
            items = new ArrayList<>(cap);
            cursor = -1;
        }

        /**
         * Initializes a new instance by setting up storage of default initial capacity. 
         */
        public MaxHeap() 
       {
            items = new ArrayList<>();
            cursor = -1;
        }

        /**
         * Sifts up the item at the given index.
         * 
         * @param index Index of item to be sifted up.
         */
        void siftUp(int index) 
       {
            T me = items.get(index);
            while (index > 0) 
          {
                int pindex = (index-1) / 2;
                T myparent = items.get(pindex);
                if (me.compareTo(myparent) > 0) 
             {
                    items.set(index, myparent);
                    index = pindex;
                }

                else break;
            }

            items.set(index, me);
        }

        /**
         * Sifts down the item at the given item.
         * 
         * @param index Index of item to be sifted down.
         */
        void siftDown(int index) 
       {
            T me = items.get(index);
            int lindex = 2*index + 1;
            while (lindex < items.size()) 
          {
                T maxChild = items.get(lindex);
                int maxIndex = lindex;

                int rindex = lindex + 1;
                if (rindex < items.size()) 
             {
                    T rightChild = items.get(rindex);
                    if (rightChild.compareTo(maxChild) > 0) 
                {
                        maxChild = rightChild;
                        maxIndex = rindex;
                    }
                }

                if (maxChild.compareTo(me) > 0) 
             {
                    items.set(index, maxChild);
                    index = maxIndex;
                    lindex = 2*index + 1;
                }

                else break;
            }
            items.set(index, me);
        }

        /**
         * Adds the given item to this heap.
         * 
         * @param item Item to be added.
         */
        public void add(T item) 
       {
            items.add(item);
            siftUp(items.size()-1);
        }

        /**
         * Removes the maximum-priority (top) item of this heap.
         * 
         * @return Removed item.
         * @throws NoSuchElementException If this heap is empty.
         */
        public T deleteMax() 
       {
            if (items.isEmpty()) 
          {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }

            T maxItem = items.get(0);
            T lastItem = items.remove(items.size() - 1);

            if (items.isEmpty()) 
          {
                return maxItem;
            }

            // move last item to vacant spot at top,and sift down 
            items.set(0, lastItem);
            siftDown(0);

            return maxItem;
        }

        /**
         * Empties this heap by removing all items. 
         */
        public void clear() 
       {
            items.clear();
        }

        /**
         * Returns the number of items in this heap.
         * 
         * @return Number of items in this heap.
         */
        public int size() 
       {
            return items.size();
        }

        /**
         * Tells whether this heap is empty or not.
         * 
         * @return True if this heap is empty, false otherwise.
         */
        public boolean isEmpty() 
       {
            return items.isEmpty();
        }

        /**
         * Returns the first item in this heap, and sets the iteration cursor to the 
         * first position. 
         * 
         * @return First item in this heap, null if list is empty.
         */
        public T first() 
       {
            if (items.isEmpty()) { return null; }
            cursor = 0;
            return items.get(cursor);
        }

        /**
         * Sets the cursor to the next position, and returns the item in this heap at
         * that position. <br> To iterate over this heap, there
         * must be a call to first( ), followed by successive calls to next( ). Iteration
         * is in level-order sequence.
         * 
         * @return Next item in this heap. Null if heap is empty, or cursor is at the 
         *         end of the heap at the time this method is called, i.e. end of heap was
         *         reached. 
         */
        public T next() 
       {
            if (cursor < 0 || cursor == (items.size() - 1)) 
          {
                return null;
            }

            cursor++;
            return items.get(cursor);
        }

       @Override
       public String toString()
       {
          String forReturn = "";

          forReturn += "Index: 0 Item: " + first();
          for(int y = 1; y < this.size(); y++)
          {
             forReturn += "Index: " + y + " Item: " + next();  
          }

          return forReturn;
       }
    }

package HeapLab;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class MinHeap<T extends Comparable<T>> 
{
    /**
     * Stores the heap items.
     */
   @SuppressWarnings("FieldMayBeFinal")
    private ArrayList<T> items;

    /**
     * Maintains iteration point. 
     */
    int cursor;

    /**
     * Initializes a new instance by setting up storage of given capacity.
     * 
     * @param cap Initial storage capacity.
     */
    public MinHeap(int cap) 
   {
        items = new ArrayList<>(cap);
        cursor = -1;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes a new instance by setting up storage of default initial capacity. 
     */
    public MinHeap() 
   {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor = -1;
    }

    /**
     * Sifts up the item at the given index.
     * 
     * @param index Index of item to be sifted up.
     */
    void siftUp(int index) 
   {
        T me = items.get(index);
        while (index > 0) 
      {
            int pindex = (index - 1) / 2;
            T myparent = items.get(pindex);
            if (me.compareTo(myparent) < 0) 
         {
                items.set(index, myparent);
                index = pindex;
            }

            else break;
        }

        items.set(index, me);
    }

    /**
     * Sifts down the item at the given item.
     * 
     * @param index Index of item to be sifted down.
     */
    void siftDown(int index) 
   {
        T me = items.get(index);
        int lindex = 2 * index + 1;
        while (lindex < items.size()) 
      {
            T minChild = items.get(lindex);
            int minIndex = lindex;

            int rindex = lindex + 1;
            if (rindex < items.size()) 
         {
                T rightChild = items.get(rindex);
                if (rightChild.compareTo(minChild) <= 0) 
            {
                    minChild = rightChild;
                    minIndex = rindex;
                }
            }

            if (minChild.compareTo(me) < 0) 
         {
                items.set(index, minChild);
                index = minIndex;
                lindex = 2 * index + 1;
            }

            else break;
        }

        items.set(index, me);
    }

    /**
     * Adds the given item to this heap.
     * 
     * @param item Item to be added.
     */
    public void add(T item) 
   {
        items.add(item);
        siftUp(items.size() - 1);
    }

    /**
     * Removes the minimum-priority (top) item of this heap.
     * 
     * @return Removed item.
     * @throws NoSuchElementException If this heap is empty.
     */
    public T deleteMin() throws ClassCastException
   {
      if (items.isEmpty())
      {
         throw new NoSuchElementException();
      }

      T minItem = items.get(0);
      T nextMinItem0 = items.get(1);
      T nextMinItem1 = items.get(2);

      if (nextMinItem0.compareTo(nextMinItem1) == -1 || nextMinItem0.compareTo(nextMinItem1) == 0)
      {
         nextMinItem0 = items.remove(1);
         items.set(0, nextMinItem0);
         siftDown(0);
      }

      else 
      { 
         nextMinItem1 = items.remove(2);
         items.set(0, nextMinItem1);
         siftDown(0);
      }

      return minItem;
   }

    /**
     * Empties this heap by removing all items. 
     */
    public void clear() 
   {
        items.clear();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of items in this heap.
     * 
     * @return Number of items in this heap.
     */
    public int size() 
   {
        return items.size();
    }

    /**
     * Tells whether this heap is empty or not.
     * 
     * @return True if this heap is empty, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() 
   {
        return items.isEmpty();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the first item in this heap, and sets the iteration cursor to the 
     * first position. 
     * 
     * @return First item in this heap, null if list is empty.
     */
    public T first() 
   {
        if (items.isEmpty()) { return null; }
        cursor = 0;
        return items.get(cursor);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the cursor to the next position, and returns the item in this heap at
     * that position. <br> To iterate over this heap, there
     * must be a call to first( ), followed by successive calls to next( ). Iteration
     * is in level-order sequence.
     * 
     * @return Next item in this heap. Null if heap is empty, or cursor is at the 
     *         end of the heap at the time this method is called, i.e. end of heap was
     *         reached. 
     */
    public T next() 
   {
        if (cursor < 0 || cursor == (items.size() - 1)) 
      {
            return null;
        }

        cursor++;
        return items.get(cursor);
    }

   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
      String forReturn = "";

      forReturn += "Index: 0 Item: " + first();
      for(int y = 1; y < this.size(); y++)
      {
         forReturn += "Index: " + y + " Item: " + next();  
      }

      return forReturn;
   }
}

package HeapLab;

import java.util.Random;

public class TestHeaps
{
   private static final int heapSize = 30;
   private static MaxHeap<Integer> maxHeap;
   private static MinHeap<Integer> minHeap;
   private static Random generate;
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.println("Program start");

      minHeap = new MinHeap<>(heapSize);
      maxHeap = new MaxHeap<>(heapSize);

      minHeap = minHeapRandom(minHeap);
      maxHeap = maxHeapRandom(maxHeap);

      deleteMinToScreen(minHeap);
      deleteMaxToScreen(maxHeap);
   }

   static MinHeap<Integer> minHeapRandom(MinHeap<Integer> heap)
   {
      generate = new Random();   int newRandom;
      for(int y = 0; y < heap.size(); y++)
      {
         newRandom = generate.nextInt(100);
         heap.add(newRandom);
      }

      return heap;
   }

   static MaxHeap<Integer> maxHeapRandom(MaxHeap<Integer> heap)
   {
      generate = new Random();   int newRandom;
      for(int r = 0; r < heap.size(); r++)
      {
         newRandom = generate.nextInt(100);
         heap.add(newRandom);
      }

      return heap;
   }

   static void deleteMinToScreen(MinHeap<Integer> heap)
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < heap.size(); i++)
      {
         System.out.println("Index: " + i + " Item: " + heap.deleteMin());
      }
   }

   static void deleteMaxToScreen(MaxHeap<Integer> heap)
   {
      for(int j = 0; j < heap.size(); j++)
      {
         System.out.println("Index: " + j + " Item: " + heap.deleteMax());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is all of this code related to your problem? Or only some of it?

Comment: The best way to find out what is related -- use a debugger.

Comment: I guess all related but the problem with ArrayList is mysterious as the code works in NetBeans without a problem but because the ArrayList is stuck with size 0.

Comment: This can't possibly be correct.  In `siftUp`, the code `items.set(index, myparent);` _replaces_ the item at `index` with a reference to `myparent`.  Whatever was at `index` is discarded.  Are you sure that's what you intended?  Same goes for `siftDown`.